# What happens if I have an essential singularity and a pole for the same $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, residue-calculus, singularity

for instance  $$\dfrac{\sin(\dfrac{1}{z})}{z}$$

$z=0$ is a pole for the denominator
but $z=0$ is an essential singularity for the numerator too.
So how does it work ? i have two residues ? or it's different some way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z=0$ is an essential singularity for your function too. with the expansion 
$sin z=\sum_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ we see
$$\frac{1}{z}sin \frac{1}{z}=\sum_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!z^{2n+2}}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{3!z^4}+\frac{1}{5!z^6}-...$$
Can you find the residue?

Comment: ah maybe because the series of sin(1/z) has infiniely z at the denominator , so if i multiply by 1/z we will continue to have infinitlky z at the denominator ( also with a major grade) is this the reason ?

Comment: the residue is the coefficient of the one with lower grade ? so is 1 ?

Comment: ahh so it would be the 1/z coefficient ?

Comment: thank you accepting this